# How to implement vertical image slider using jquery in which before showing new image it will close and open with a new image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to implement vertical image slider using jquery in which before showing new image it will close and open with  a new image.

For example check this one http://www.timeinc.com/home/
This was developed using flash, but i want to implement it using jQuery.
Is there any plugin for that or any other help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about jQuery but i think this sample may help you:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div> </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    width:10%;
    height:40%;
    background:red;
    right:45%;
    bottom:50%;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}
div:hover {
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it should be move up and down automatically,not by  mouse over